# Converting Old Khan academy Project To VS code

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, khan-academy

This is an old Khan academy project that I made.
I'm wondering how I can convert this to work on an external website.

It was a small magic 8 ball project. I think that how you put things into Khan Academy's editor doesn't read outside their environment very well.

```js
fill(0, 0, 0);
ellipse(200, 200, 375, 375);
fill(60, 0, 255);
triangle(200, 104, 280, 280, 120, 280);
fill(255, 255, 255);
var answer = floor(random(1, 6));
if (answer === 1) {   // response one
    fill(235, 9, 9);
    textSize(30);
    text("NOT", 171, 202);
    text('A',190,233);
    text("CHANCE", 137, 267); 
}
    
    else if (answer === 2)  // response two
  { 
      fill(76, 199, 14);
      textSize(23);
      text('FOR',176,207);
      textSize(40);
      text('SURE',144,250);
  }
  
    else if (answer === 3) // response three
    { 
        fill(245, 245, 12);
        textSize(30);
        text('ASK',170,197);
        text('AGAIN',154,230);
        text('LATER',153,261);
        
    }
else if (answer === 4) // response four
{
    fill(204, 138, 25);
    textSize(20);
    text('ANSWER',157,214);
    textSize(24);
    text('UNCLEAR',145,251);
    

}

else  // response five
{
    fill(218, 12, 237);
    textSize(19);
    text('MAGIC',170,198);
    text('8 BALL',170,232);
    textSize(19);
    text('MALFUNCTION',132,268);
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: *"Im very new to coding and VS code..."* VS Code is an editor, not a runtime engine, not an IDE, since javascript is not compiled in your usage of it.

Comment: No one needs to learn VSCode. Apparently Khan Academy set up an environment with predefined functions. Figure out what the predefined functions do and rocket.

Comment: so i just need to run this from a app.js file in vs?